# Snowflake fill null values

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like this in Snowflake, where I have a "class" column, where all rows with level 1 have a value. I would like to have a new column "WANTED_OUTPUT", where the value from class are filled until new value occurs, then fill with that value.

I have been looking at first_value and last_value function, but I miss something there can "group" all the rows from level 1 until next level 1 together before I can use the first_value and the partition over that.

Any suggestion?

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+---------------+
| id | col_c | level | class | WANTED_OUTPUT |
+----+-------+-------+-------+---------------+
| a  | q1    | 1     | c99   | c99           |
+----+-------+-------+-------+---------------+
| a  | w2    | 2     | NULL  | c99           |
+----+-------+-------+-------+---------------+
| a  | g6    | 2     | NULL  | c99           |
+----+-------+-------+-------+---------------+
| a  | j5    | 3     | NULL  | c99           |
+----+-------+-------+-------+---------------+
| a  | x8    | 1     | c3    | c3            |
+----+-------+-------+-------+---------------+
| a  | x9    | 2     | NULL  | c3            |
+----+-------+-------+-------+---------------+
| a  | h5    | 1     | c67   | c67           |
+----+-------+-------+-------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `FIRST/LAST_VALUE`:

```
SELECT *,
   FIRST_VALUE(class) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY level) AS wanted
FROM tab;
```

Tables are unordered sets by design so stable sort is required. Level may not be enough based on provided input.

---

Suggestion:  Adding explicit timestamp or seq id column to provide stable sort column would be preferred.

```
SELECT tab.*,    
   LAST_VALUE(class) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY id 
                     ORDER BY rn
                     RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                    ) AS wanted 
FROM tab;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8f05c660782a308b505d30addc34c392)**

---

EDIT:

Using `COALESCE` and `LAG`:

```
SELECT tab.*,    
COALESCE(class,LAG(class) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rn)) AS wanted 
FROM tab;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: In my small example row 1 to 4 are some how the same group based on my ID column and level  and row 5-6 are another group same ID, but a new "level 1" and row 7 is it own group, I thing that should be translated to "helper" column to partition over. But I do not know how to do that.

Comment: @jvels You could build some unreliable behavior, but without stable sort it is not feasible. `WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS rn FROM tab) SELECT *,    FIRST_VALUE(class) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rn) AS wanted FROM cte`; - here there is an implicit assumption than when creating rn the data is read as it was inserted. I suggest adding explicit timestamp or id column to provide stable sort column.

Comment: Getting `002303 (0A000): SQL compilation error: error line 3 at position 93
Cumulative window frame unsupported for function LAST_VALUE` when i ran with `LAST_VALUE`

Comment: I have same question, the solution inst working in snowflake .

Comment: @KoushikRoy Alternative approach using LAG has been added

Comment: hmm, even lag dint work but `coalesce(col_01 , lag(col_01) ignore nulls over (partition by col_NAME) output`